# js destruct a sub-object inner object

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, ecmascript-6

I assign a object:

```
const info = { name: 'Peter', location: { province: 1, city: 2 } };
let { name } = info;
console.log(name); // 'Peter'

// then how to get location.province
let { 'location.province': province } = info;
console.log(province); // 'undefined'
```

how to I get sub-object location.province by deconstruct???

Comment: ```let { province } = info.location;```

Comment: @Wainage thanks, maybe has some better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing "nested" destructuring:

```
let {name, location: {province}} = info;
```

For such questions, always look at MDN first because it usually [has many examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Nested_object_and_array_destructuring).